# How to get ConnectionString from EF7 DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

### My Scenario:

I'm using EF7 for standard CRUD operations and Dapper for more complex queries that require increase in speed. From startup.cs I'm injecting my `DbContext` into my DAL which does then obviously does the database queries. Dapper requires a connection string. I want to inject my EF7 DbContext connection string into the Dapper query.

### My Question:

How do I get the connection string from the DbContext like before: `DbContext.Database.Connection`?

It changed from `Database` to `DatabaseFacade` type in EF7, and with that, `DbConnection Connection` was also removed.

Surely there should be some persistent connection string in the `DbContext` that I can query?

### My Research:

The method I'm using at the moment is, and it works:

```
public partial class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    public readonly string _connectionString;

    public CustomContext (DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
            _connectionString = ((SqlServerOptionsExtension)options.Extensions.First()).ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

**I know its still in beta, but am I missing something?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: FYI i'm using beta7 of EF7.

Comment: Side note: you should consider using the .FromSql(query) and .AsNoTracking() methods to improve EF's query speed so you don't need Dapper + EF in one project.

Comment: You lead me right. This works for me.ctor:  public DbContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {
            this.Database = new DatabaseFacade(this);
        }

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've searched EF7 [sources](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework) and it seems that you are correct with your current approach.

Connection string is stored in `SqlServerOptionsExtension`. When you call `UseSqlServer(connectionString)` [the code](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dc30d95a3740c5b9a7a6bfe88bdc556626daf539/src/EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.cs) is as follows (extracted only interesting lines):

```
var extension = options.FindExtension<SqlServerOptionsExtension>()
extension.ConnectionString = connectionString;
```

I'm not sure why connection string was removed from obvious place, but it may be that devs abstracted away connection string to allow us to use non-standard databases (like in-memory database etc.).

This looks much clearer IMO:

```
Configuration.Get("Data:ConnectionString")
```

Answer (score 9):

If you have a fully materialized context, you can also use this:

```
 var conn = context.Database.GetDbConnection();
 ConnectionString = conn?.ConnectionString;
 conn?.Dispose();
```

Comment: This works great but bear in mind the password will no longer be available after a connection is opened, unless Persist Security Info is set to true in the connection string.